# Initialization difference between static and dynamic allocation

Tags: c++, memory, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm trying to find what is the difference between the static and the dynamic allocation of the table in this code, I'm interested most about the initial state or values n that table.

when I tried the code with the static allocation the program didn't work and i can see that the table contain random value but with the dynamic allocation it works better.

can someone explain to me how this work thanks.

```
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std ;

bool isUnique(std::string s)
{
    if(s.length()> 128 ) return false;

    //bool lettre[128];
    bool* lettre = new bool[128];
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        int index = s[i];
        if (lettre[index] == true)
            return false;
        lettre[index] = true;
    }
    for(int i=0; i<128;i++)
    {
        cout<< lettre[i] +" |";
    }
    cout<<endl;
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    std::string s1 = "adcadef";
    std::string s2 = "abcdef";

    cout<< isUnique(s1) << endl;
    cout << isUnique(s2) << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You allocated memory but never initialized it, yet you return false if it contains true?

Comment: Using uninitialized variables can do that. Give `bool lettre[128] = {};` a try. Note it's just dumb bad luck that the dynamic version worked for you.

Comment: My C++ is rusty but: this is a static allocation of memory `bool* lettre = new bool[128]`. You obtain it from the "stack" memory. A dynamic allocation of memory comes from the "heap" memory. You must use keyword `new` to create it and the keyword `delete` to destroy it.  You can control the exact size and lifetime of it.

Comment: @user4581301 even with the dynamic version the array with be initialized with random value ?

Comment: sorry @TonyTannous but i didn't get your question can you explain more, thanks

Comment: @rej the default initialization for a `bool` is to do nothing.